# How to raise event click on Purechat with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to capture eachtime user click on Purechat Widget (a online chat service for website, https://www.purechat.com/) on my Website to count Conversion.
I'm using a script as follow:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
   jQuery(document).ready( function(){

    jQuery(".purechat-widget-header").click( function(){
      alert("Hello 2");
    });
  })    
</script>
```

But the function alert("Hello 2") do not run when I click on the Widget.

Purechat use JS to add HTML of chat widget on Website after load Web.
Normally, the event are raised on other HTML element which are generated from server side, but HTML element generated by Purechat, it does not.

This is the jsfiddle for test: https://jsfiddle.net/qor1jkpa/1/

Please help me to fix the problem,

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use event **[delegate](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

Like this

```
jQuery(docuemnt).on("click",".purechat-widget-header",function(){
  alert("Hello 2");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but It is still does not work, Purechat use JS to add HTML of chat widget on Website after load Web.
Normally, the event are raised on other HTML element which are generated from server side, but HTML element generated by Purechat.

Comment: @TuanNguyen can you provide plnukr or jsfiddle ?

Comment: @TuanNguyen handle `mousedown` instead of `click` . check here https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/qor1jkpa/2/

Comment: I've tried your script on another Live Chat (subiz), but It does not work, can you help me more: https://jsfiddle.net/549rzpe1/3/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is trying to attach an event to the PureChat window, be sure to check out the API chatbox events documentation: https://purechat.com/support/javascript-api#region=chatbox-events

I was able to accomplish what I was needing to do by using:

`purechatApi.on('chatbox:expand', function (args) {
    // do this!!
});`