# How to raise event when click on livechat using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I neen to capture event eachtime user click on Livechat on my Website. A stackoverflower helped me to solve problem on Purechat, but the solution do not work with Subiz (another Livechat).

Refer old solution for purechat: [How to raise event click on Purechat with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770443/how-to-raise-event-click-on-purechat-with-jquery/33770499)

My code is as follow:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on("mousedown", ".sbzon", function (){        
        console.log("clicked on"); // do not work
    });

    jQuery(document).on("mousedown", ".sbzoff", function () {
        console.log("clicked sbzoff"); // do not work
    });

    jQuery(document).on("mousedown", "p", function () {
        console.log("clicked p"); // only this work
    });


});
```

Please help me, this is the jsfiddle link of problem:

```
https://goo.gl/mpe0Mn
```

Thanks so much,

Comment: Are you sure about these class names `.sbzon` and `.sbzoff`, which are generated dynamically by LiveChat?

Comment: And post the code here by using stack snippets.

Comment: Yes, Subiz generated dynamically the chat widget, 2 class .sbzon and sbzoff are generated by Subiz.

Answer (score 2):

Subiz Live Chat use iframe to keep their widget dom elements. Events: click... on widget is holded on iframe window, not delegate to parent window (your site) so you can't bind event as: jQuery(document).on('.sbzon', 'click', function...), event never fire.

I have a solution to capture event click on Subiz widget, use document.activeElement to track current on parent site or iframe Subiz. (may be useful for other case :)), see below:

```js
function visitorClickedOnSubizLiveChat() {
    alert('yes');
};

setInterval(function() {
    if (document.activeElement) {
         if (document.activeElement.id === 'sbzon_frame' || document.activeElement.id === 'sbzoff_frame') {
             visitorClickedOnSubizLiveChat();
         }

         window.focus();
         // or document.activeElement.blur();
    }
}, 600);
```

Good luck!

Update link test: http://jsfiddle.net/tuanlongn/apvp2xvc/

Comment: Thanks you so much, there is still problem:
Problem 1: function alert is repeat each 600ms after click on chat -> I fixed this.

Problemt 2: I can't know which sub-item was clicked by user, I prefer to know when user click to expand chat box, and do not capture eachtime user click to minimize chat box.

If you have another solution, please let me to know.
Thanks so much,